# Converting SVG path data into GDI+ GraphicsPath data

Tags: c#, svg, gdi+, graphicspath

Is there an easy way to convert an SVG path tag into a C# System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath? They are both closely related and I was hoping there would be an easy to convert the SVG path data into GraphicsPath Points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This SVG project](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) provides a solution in the following way:

```
var pathData = ...;

var graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();

foreach (var segment in SvgPathBuilder.Parse(pathData))
    segment.AddToPath(graphicsPath);

graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, graphicsPath);
```

It's available as a NuGet package via:

```
PM> Install-Package Svg
```

Comment: How have you accessed `SvgPathBuilder` ? Its an internal class.. Reflection ?

Comment: @Pogrindis, are you using the NuGet package? Perhaps I was using an older version. Sorry, it's been a while and I don't recall. I wouldn't have used reflection though -- just the code shown.

Comment: @Pogrindis, looks like the class is public: https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/Paths/SvgPathBuilder.cs

Comment: thanks! It looks like I was using an older version! :(

Answer (score 4):

There's no easy way, although SVG paths and `GraphicsPath` look similar and serve the same purpose, there are some differences in how things are specified and handled. One example: SVG arc definition is different from how `GraphicsPath` defines arcs, so you'll need to do a little bit of trigonometry to convert it.

Also check out [Drawing SVG in .NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525421/drawing-svg-in-net-c)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this ain't late! Check out the source code of the svg viewer program from AGG: [https://github.com/timothytylee/agg/tree/master/examples/svg_viewer](http://www.antigrain.com/svg/index.html)

The source code is in C++ and uses the AGG graphics engine, but it's easy to translate to GDI+. It also handles the conversion of SVG Arc to a Bezier Arc which can then be used with GDI+.

Good luck

Comment: The specified link no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated.

If the svg path only consists of `M L Q Z ZM` functions your method looks like this:

```
private GraphicsPath svgMLQZToGraphicsPath(string svgString)
{
    GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
    float[] x = new float[4];
    float[] y = new float[4];
    string prev = "";
    string[] splits = svgString.Split(' ');
    for (int s = 0; s < splits.Length; s++)
    {
        if (splits[s].Substring(0, 1) == "M")
        {
            x[0] = float.Parse(splits[s].Substring(1).Replace('.', ','));
            y[0] = float.Parse(splits[s + 1].Replace('.', ','));
            s++;
            prev = "M";
            graphicsPath.StartFigure();
        }
        else if (splits[s].Substring(0, 1) == "L")
        {
            x[1] = float.Parse(splits[s].Substring(1).Replace('.', ','));
            y[1] = float.Parse(splits[s + 1].Replace('.', ','));
            graphicsPath.AddLine(new PointF(x[0], y[0]), new PointF(x[1], y[1]));
            x[0] = x[1]; // x[1] = new float();
            y[0] = y[1]; //y[1] = new float();
            s++;
            prev = "L";
        }
        else if (splits[s].Substring(0, 1) == "Q")
        {
            x[1] = x[0] + (2 / 3) * (float.Parse(splits[s].Substring(1).Replace('.', ',')) - x[0]);
            y[1] = y[0] + (2 / 3) * (float.Parse(splits[s + 1].Replace('.', ',')) - y[0]);
            x[3] = float.Parse(splits[s + 2].Replace('.', ','));
            y[3] = float.Parse(splits[s + 3].Replace('.', ','));
            x[2] = x[3] + (2 / 3) * (float.Parse(splits[s].Substring(1).Replace('.', ',')) - y[3]);
            y[2] = y[3] + (2 / 3) * (float.Parse(splits[s + 1].Replace('.', ',')) - y[3]);
            graphicsPath.AddBezier(new PointF(x[0], y[0]), new PointF(x[1], y[1]), new PointF(x[2], y[2]), new PointF(x[3], y[3]));
            x[0] = x[3]; 
            y[0] = y[3]; 
            s = s + 3;
            prev = "Q";
        }
        else if (splits[s].Substring(0, 1) == "Z")
        {
            graphicsPath.CloseFigure();
            if (splits[s].Length >= 2 && splits[s].Substring(0, 2) == "ZM")
            {
                x[0] = float.Parse(splits[s].Substring(2).Replace('.', ','));
                y[0] = float.Parse(splits[s + 1].Replace('.', ','));
                s++;
                graphicsPath.StartFigure();
                prev = "M";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string ok = @"^[a-zA-Z]*$";
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(splits[s + 1].Substring(0, 1), ok))
            {
                string replace = prev + splits[s + 1];
                splits[s + 1] = replace;
            }
        }
    }
    return graphicsPath;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work as it is, but gave me an interesting prototype which I converted to Delphi.