# How can a block diagram be dynamically generated in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Based on the data, I need to dynamically generate a graphic in my ASP.NET page.
What is the best way to do this. Is this easier to implement in Silverlight.

Comment: you will have to find a control to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any graphics library, including the classes in the [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace.

Comment: So it will be rendered as a bitmap?

Comment: @andromeda - That's up to you, but yes, that's what the namespace is all about - images.

Comment: can it be rendered as a vector image?

Comment: @andromeda - Not as far as I know, but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525421/drawing-svg-in-net-c).

Answer (score 0):

no, SL in not absolutely needed, you can draw it line by line using GDI+ (Managed GDI APIs) on the server side from C#.

SL could help a bit but it really depends if you want then to bind your application to a plugin. I would not, just to be cross platform (including mobile devices)...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create the image on the server side and returns via
   httpHandler
2. TO draw on the client side using javascript you can find a
   special librarise like
   [this](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/)
3. You can use Silverlight or Flash
4. I'm not sure but probably it can be done via CSS3

Comment: it's not CSS3, it's HTML5 and canvas :)

Comment: maybe :) I know that new technologies allow to do this but here is still problems with cross-browser i think. Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend using http://raphaeljs.com/

You could create server side code to do it using system.drawing, but Raphael can do it all in the browser, saving you a round trip.