# Convert SVG-stream to png or jpg

Tags: c#, pdf, png, itext, jpeg

I would like to use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to add images to some PDF-documents using C#.

My problem is, that the images are saved as a stream (fx. M47,33 L47,34 L47,37 L47,40 L47 etc.) in the database.

I can't figure out, how to convert this to PNG or JPEG so I can add them to the PDF-documents.

Can anyone tell me how to make this convertion, or if it can be done directly in iText?

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525421/drawing-svg-in-net-c

Answer (score 2):

[Converting SVG images to png in c#](http://harriyott.com/2008/05/converting-svg-images-to-png-in-c.aspx)

Comment: The linked article describes an "interesting" way of conversion if you don't mind calling Inkscape via its command-line interface (which brings some more points of failure to your application).

Comment: As described in a comment below, I'm not able to install third-party software on the customer's server. As far as I understand, this rules out InkScape?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/

It does not have a `C#` binding as far as I can see, but it should be possible to use it via P/Invoke.

EDIT: iText seems to have some conversion, too: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=263

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm using c# for my application. The example from iText is written in Java.

Comment: At this moment I just need to get something running on my desktop PC (proof of concept). The final "program" will be running in an ASP.NET-appication on the customer's server. I also won't be able to install any third-party software on the server, so I guess InkScape (mentioned in a lot of guides), isn't an option.

Comment: Sorry for the Java sample ;-) But what about using librsvg with P/Invoke?

Comment: Havn't gotten around to librsvg yet. Librsvg seems like a lot of work to achieve a simple thing. I have found several guides which all use a c# MemoryStream for convertion. I can't get any of these examples to work. This is strange, because I even found it on MSDN.